# Object gets duplicated after dragging with DragDelta event

Tags: c#, wpf

When I drag a newly created object, something strange happens: it get duplicated. When, I drag a duplicated object or an initial object after it was copied, it could be dragged normally. How can I avoid it and why it's happening?

Details:
1. The element (instance of a class derived from Thumb) is created programatically as follows:

```
someClass new_instance = new someClass();
new_instance.Template=template; // template is of ControlTemplate type
new_instance.DragDelta += onDragDelta;
Board.Children.Add(new_instance); // Board is of Canvas type
// code to place it on Canvas
```

The function onDragDelta is implemented as follows:

```
private void onDragDelta(object sender, DragDeltaEventArgs e)
{
    var thumb = e.Source as someClass;
    double left = Canvas.GetLeft(thumb) + e.HorizontalChange;
    double top = Canvas.GetLeft(thumb) + e.HorizontalChange;
    Canvas.SetLeft(thumb,left);
    Canvas.SetTop(thumb,top);
}
```

Could some conclusion be made or a hint be given from the information provided?

Comment: from you description, it is very likely that 2 elements have been created and placed at the same location, before you dragging the upper one away. How can you know it is duplicated at the time you drag the newly created object?

Comment: You're right, it was created twice and placed at the same location! Thus, DragDelta works correctly. Thanks, you solved my problem!